# Having problems accessing the host's hard drive in VMware

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware

I recently installed VMware 10.0.0 in my Windows 7 and created a Ubuntu Gnome 64. I want to set up a shared folder with your host OS, my D:/, so I can work with the projects located there.

Searching through out the web to see how that was done, I came to [this answer here in Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/250335/how-do-i-access-the-hosts-hard-drive-in-vmware/) which tells exactly what I want, but with 2 problems:

1. I attempted to follow the procedure, but I didn’t get success; the folder I wanted to share never appeared in `/mount/hgfs`. Things got to a point where I complitely erased my Ubuntu and now I’m trying to “start from zero.”
2. There seems to be some problems with that manual though. For instance, when I was creating this last virtual machine, it told me that “VMware Tools were being installed.” And if I go the VM Player status after the “[Install VMware Tools](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-vmware-tools-on-ubuntu-edgy-with-vmware-553/)” menu button, what I get is *reinstall VMware Tools*, clearly indicating that this was indeed installed. But when [I run the commands](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-share-folders-with-your-ubuntu-virtual-machine-guest/) `lsmod | grep vmhgfs` (and get nothing, then I run) `modprobe vmhgfs`, I get a message saying that “vmhgfs was not found.” And that is supposed to indicate VMware Tools are not installed!
3. I noticed the manuals are not updated: they talk about version 5, while my VMware is version 10.0 as mentioned above.

So given the “not updated” situation, the strange behaviour and the fact that previously my attempts failed, could someone please give my an updated guide as to how set up a shared folder with your host OS, Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

After you click the Install VMWare Tools, do you get a popup that includes "Mount the virtual CD drive in the guest, ..."?

I don't believe I've run a guest with your exact OS but if the module isn't found, my thought is that the VMWare Tools weren't compiled and installed.  In my experience, you have to mount /dev/cdrom on a directory, extract the VMWareTools-*-tar.gz, and run the installer.

Hard to know what the problem is exactly without seeing your guest, but this is where I'd start.  Hope this helps.

Basic Example:

```
mount /dev/cdrom /mnt
cd /tmp
tar -zxvf /mnt/VMwareTools-9.2.3-1031360.tar.gz
cd vmware-tools-distrib
./vmware-install.pl
```

Comment: well, as I sad, the button "Install VMware Tools" don't even appear since, as it all seems, it is already installed! And now I remember that when I click in the only available button, "**reinstall** VMware Tools", it does mount something on a CD with a .tar.gz file, and when I do the proceedings listed here (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-vmware-tools-on-ubuntu-edgy-eft/), which now I noticed is the not updated instructions (but anyway, the lastest one is also not updated), it even says that VMware Tools is *already* installed, confirming previous appearences.