# Transer from file from Windows to Linux in WMWare

Tags: windows, ubuntu, vmware-workstation

I have Windows OS in which I have installed VMWare.VMWare has Ubuntu in it as Virtual OS.Now I try to copy my Windows Desktop to Ubuntu Folder but it is not working.Is there a way to do this? Please find the image for reference.

[image]

Comment: install VMWare Tools

Answer (score -2):

You need to set up a shared folder to access host OS files. Here are specific instructions from [this very similar answer](https://superuser.com/questions/250335/how-do-i-access-the-hosts-hard-drive-in-vmware):

> In the VM settings under shared folders, click Add and follow the
>   on-screen prompts
>
> When you're done, your share will show up under the /mount/hgfs
>   directory.

Comment: If another questions answer, answers this question, then this question should be marked as a duplicate.